# why does calling the user-defined function gravity() produce this error message?

Tags: python

i'm a beginner in python, i called a function "gravity" before defining it and when i tried running the code, the python interpreter seems to produce this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/day1.py", line 30, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "C:/Python34/day1.py", line 22, in main
    gravity(78,98)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'gravity' referenced before assignment
```

Here is the code

```
def main():

    person = people()
    person2 = people("joel max")



    print(person2.whatname())


    gravity(78,98)


    def gravity(mass,accel):
        force = mass * accel

        return force

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

i tried to adjust the indentation but it's still not working.

Comment: Because you are calling `gravity()` before you've defined it.  Move the call after the `def`

Comment: Why are you defining `gravity` inside `main`? And why do you ignore and discard the return value when you call it?

Comment: i want to print out the value of gravity based on the parameters passed to it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to call **gravity** before you defined it.  Also, there's no reason to define it within your main program; make it a separate, external function.  After the below changes, your only problem is that there's no function **people**.

```
def gravity(mass,accel):
    force = mass * accel

    return force


def main():
    person = people()
    person2 = people("joel max")

    print(person2.whatname())

    gravity(78,98)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks....actually people is a class...i didn't include that section of the code

Comment: In the future ... please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We should be able to paste your posted code into a file, run it, and reproduce your problem.